# A Monk Reborn in a Lower Realm for Breaking a Leaf

Tags: reference-request

Where does the story appear about a monk who was born in a lower realm for breaking a leaf of a tree?

Also there are some related stories (use generally alongside the above) where small transgressions leading to disproportionately large karmic results. What are they and where can I find references?

Comment: Sankha told that story [in this answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9459/254) but without a reference.

Comment: This is a popular story in many Dhamma talks. I am trying to trace the source either in the Tipitaka or Commentaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the commentary to [verse 182 of the Dhammapada](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=182):

> On seeing the Buddha, Erakapatta related to the Buddha how he had been a bhikkhu during the time of Kassapa Buddha, how he had accidentally caused a grass blade to be broken off while travelling in a boat, and how he had worried over that little offence for having failed to do the act of exoneration as prescribed, and finally how he was reborn as a naga.

Comment: What does it mean by "Having failed to do the act of exoneration as prescribed"?

Comment: Monks have (many) monastic rules: page 272 of [this document](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf) says, "The damaging of a living plant is to be confessed". So if a monk damages a living plant, they should "confess" that, i.e. tell another monk or tell the whole community of monks that they did that, described on page 161: "This confession is what clears him of the offense". So this act of the confession is what's meant by the "prescribed act of exoneration".

Comment: ah I see now. Thanks for taking the time to explain this.